# PHP - Regex for routing

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to create a mock regex pattern that filters laravel like routes but I'm having trouble getting my regular expression figured out. I want to replace {variable} from the route and match it to a uri.

example:

**Route:**

```
 /user/{id}
 /user/{id}/edit
```

**URI:**

```
/user/1
/user/1/edit
```

Current Code (following code is in a foreach loop that iterates through routes)

```
//escape slashes
$pattern = '/^' . str_replace("/", '\/', $route) . '$/i';
//strip out variables from route to compare with uri
$pattern = preg_replace('/\{(.*?)\}/', '(.*?)', $pattern);

if (preg_match($pattern, $uri)){
     echo "Found a match.";
}
```

The issue is that when the second uri above(/user/1/edit) is entered into the browser, it will match it to the first route instead of the second route.  I assume because I'm replacing the variable({id}) with (.*?) so it will match anything after the variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem can be [demonstrated as thus](http://ideone.com/PAAJdL) (which is an actual *minimal* test-case, work on creating these!)

```
preg_match("{^/(.*?)/(.*?)/$}", "/foo/bar/", $matches);
var_dump($matches);    // captures -> "foo", "bar"

preg_match("{^/(.*?)/$}", "/foo/bar/", $matches);
var_dump($matches);    // captures -> "foo/bar"
```

This is because the non-greedy "?" qualifier says "matches as little as *can* be matched while *still* making the best attempt to match". In the second case the regular expression engine *first* tried to match just "foo" and then since the pattern failed the regular expression *backtracked* and the capture was forced to capture "foo/bar".

The solution is to *prohibit* the group from capturing anything it is not allowed to capture.

```
preg_match("{^/([^/]+)/$}", "/foo/bar/", $matches);
var_dump($matches);    // match failed
```